# Getting path of file saved in memory or as temp file using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-python-console, file-path, qgis-3

Whenever I do something like buffer in QGIS with Vector >> Geoprocessing Tools >> Buffer... the source output I get for my temporary file looks like this:

[image]

That works fine if I'm doing more QGIS actions, but then I need to use r.patch and for it to work I need to put actual paths as inputs(or if I don't tell me how to make it accept the source above).

If I do it manually, it knows the path and if I go in the processing history I can see he used:
C:/Users/Phil/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_534fdc910b13414bbab4810d36304212/15b103f620a74a189c2370a8abee2ba0/output.tif

But I have no idea how to go get that path. Right now this is how my buffer looks:

```py
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:buffer", \
{'INPUT':tmp_riv_ponc_Intersect_Clipped,\
'DISTANCE':1.5,\
'SEGMENTS':5,\
'END_CAP_STYLE':0,\
'JOIN_STYLE':0,\
'MITER_LIMIT':2,\
'DISSOLVE':False,\
'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Buffered')[0].setName('Riv_Ponc_Intersect_Buffered')
tmp_riv_ponc_Intersect_Buffered = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Riv_Ponc_Intersect_Buffered')[0].source()
```

And the tmp_riv_ponc_Intersect_Buffered gives the source of the picture shown above.
I also tried to use the same line but instead of source I put ".dataProvider().dataSourceUri()" but it gave me pretty much the same thing except a couple of lines from the Source were missing.

I also tried to put "memory:" instead of TEMPORARY_OUTPUT but didn't change anything.
I tried to do:

```py
output_path = processing.runAndLoadResults(...
{'OUTPUT': 'output_22c6c1b4_1c03_44c8_92dd_3dffc7a6a0d8'} #Output = "memory:"
{'OUTPUT': 'Clipped_5b605e64_620d_4ac4_a1b1_64a329f6c2b5'} #Output = "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"
```

They were done on a different processing algorithm, but "memory:" always gives output_... and the temporary gives me the name of the action like Clipped_...

I have found no way of getting the complete path to the temp folder where the files should be.

Comment: There is already an issue in your reasoning. You tell us you run `native:buffer`. It returns a vector layer. The input from `r.patch` are one or more raster. There is a missing part between the two IMHO. The `r.patch` GRASS doc confirms it grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.patch.html#parameters You need between both to "Rasterize" your vector buffer.

Comment: You are correct I just gave to pieces of code to explain the problem, I can update it and give a bigger portion of code instead

Comment: No, it's fine. At least I understand. You may look at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36618. Could be related to your issue depending of you QGIS version. Fix in the issue = 19 days ago. Last 3.10 release = 25 days ago. Need to build QGIS to confirm or wait for the next QGIS 3.10 release minor version package.

Comment: Nevermind you actually helped me find my mistake. My rasterize was with processing.run() instead of processing.runAndLoadResults() so I thought it was a path error but the layer simply wasn't there to begin with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThomasG77 helped me realize I forgot to use processing.runAndLoadResults and instead I used only processing.run for my rasterize which meant my raster layer had never been added to my project and I was trying to access something that wasn't there.

for reference here was my rasterize code before:

```
processing.run("grass7:v.to.rast", \
{'input':tmp_riv_ponc_Intersect_Buffered,\
'type':[0,1,3],\
'where':'',\
'use':2,\
'attribute_column':None,\
'rgb_column':None,\
'label_column':None,\
'value':1,\
'memory':300,\
'output':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',\
'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None,\
'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':cellsize,\
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT':'',\
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META':'',\
'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER':-1,\
'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER':0.0001})

QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Rasterized')[0].setName('Riv_Ponc_Intersect_Rasterized')
tmp_riv_ponc_Intersect_Rasterized = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Riv_Ponc_Intersect_Rasterized')[0].source()
```

And now the updated version:

```
processing.runAndLoadResults("grass7:v.to.rast", \
{'input':tmp_riv_ponc_Intersect_Buffered,\
'type':[0,1,3],\
'where':'',\
'use':2,\
'attribute_column':None,\
'rgb_column':None,\
'label_column':None,\
'value':1,\
'memory':300,\
'output':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',\
'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None,\
'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':cellsize,\
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT':'',\
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META':'',\
'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER':-1,\
'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER':0.0001})

QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Rasterized')[0].setName('Riv_Ponc_Intersect_Rasterized')
tmp_riv_ponc_Intersect_Rasterized = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Riv_Ponc_Intersect_Rasterized')[0].source()
```